# Is locking necessary for writing to files in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, locking

In an ASP.NET application that is constantly reading and writing into xml files, is it necessary to place a lock in the file manipulation section of the code?  The possibility exists that two or more concurrent users could read or write to the same file.  Does anyone have any official sources for this?

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question, your server can have many requests concurrently.

Unless you try to avoid it, two requests absolutely can run concurrently.

You should use a database, which will take care of this for you.

Comment: That would be an ideal solution, but the requirements are such that xml files are necessary.